# Tkinter print specified item from list in loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I've code like below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("sample program")

def print_item_from_list(event):
    print(variable)

list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
seclist = []
print(list)
for i in range(0,5):
    variable = list[i]
    sample = Label(text=variable)
    sample.pack()
    sample.bind('<Enter>', print_item_from_list)

root.mainloop()
```

What I want to achieve is that everytime my pointer enter label 'Sample', specified item form list is printed (i.e. when I hover over label '2', I want second object from my list to get printed). I tried already changing **variable** to **list[i]** (Just for tests if it would work) and creating second list and appending to it, but with no luck. My guess is it's somehow connected to Tkniter behaviour.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259072/tkinter-bind-function-with-variable-in-a-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of closures:

```
for i in range(0,5):
    variable = list[i]
    sample = Label(text=variable)
    sample.pack()
    def connect_callback(variable):
        sample.bind('<Enter>', lambda event:print(variable))
    connect_callback(variable)
```

This creates a new callback function with a fixed value for each label. In your code, all callbacks refer to the same `variable`, but with this solution every callback has its own `variable`.

Answer (score 2):

**With your code :**

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("sample program")

def print_item_from_list(event):
    print(event.widget.config("text")[-1])


list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
seclist = []
print(list)
for i in range(0,5):
    variable = list[i]
    sample = Label(text=variable)
    sample.pack()
    sample.bind('<Enter>', print_item_from_list)

root.mainloop()
```